# Hex game with arrow of walkthrough over board

Tags: arrows

I want to know if it's possible to do an arrow of a walkthrough of an Hex board game using the hexgame package. Anyone knows a way to do this?

The idea is to make something like the arrow in this link:

[image]

But doing in the package hexgame, that shows a board like this:

[image]

If it's not possible to do in the hexgame package, how can I do the first image in Latex code considering the arrow and the thick black line?

Comment: Could you lay the foundation of what you're talking about by means of a working minimal example?

Comment: In fact the only thing I have about that images is a latex package. That's the reason of why I want to know how to do those images and why I don't have a code to show.

Comment: It's doable, as was shown below with the `hexboard` package. It's basic`tikz` . I suggest spending some time on the minimal document and more specialized on the big manual found at: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de .

Answer (score 3):

Here I use the package hexboard. Drawing the board (`\hexboard`) and shading the cells (`\hexcellshaded`) are part of hexboard. That package also has a command `\hexconnect` for drawing a line between two cells, though here I rewrite this command to add `dotted` so the line is dotted. Then the code for drawing cell borders is new here, though based on the code in hexboard that draws the coloured edge boundaries.

[image: Hex board with labelling as described in the question]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hexboard}

% this redefines the hexboard command \hexconnect so that it has a dotted line instead of a solid one. The difference is ',dotted' in the \draw command
\renewcommand{\hexconnect}[4]{%
    \hexcoord{#1}{#2}
    \node[minimum size=0,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (A) at (\xchor em,\ychor em) {};
    \hexcoord{#3}{#4}
    \node[minimum size=0,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (B) at (\xchor em,\ychor em) {};
    \draw[line width=\hexthinline em,line cap=round,dotted] (A) -- (B);
}

% these commands are based on the code that draws the coloured edge borders in hexboard
% they draw the six parts of a cell border for the cell specified by the two arguments
\newcommand{\bottomrightcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (0 em,-0.577350 em) -- (0.5 em,-0.288675 em);}
\newcommand{\bottomleftcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (-0.5 em,-0.288675 em) -- (0 em,-0.577350 em);}
\newcommand{\toprightcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (0 em,0.577350 em) -- (0.5 em,0.288675 em);}
\newcommand{\topleftcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (-0.5 em,0.288675 em) -- (0 em,0.577350 em);}
\newcommand{\leftcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (-0.5 em,-0.288675 em) -- (-0.5 em,0.288675 em);}
\newcommand{\rightcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (0.5 em,-0.288675 em) -- (0.5 em,0.288675 em);}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % a hexpicture environment is really a tikzpicture environment, so we can use tikz arrows.meta to draw arrowheads

\begin{document}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        % shade some cells
        % \hexcellshaded is a hexboard command that draws a shaded cell. We do it before drawing the actual \hexboard so that the edge border of the \hexboard is above the shading.
        \hexcellshaded{a}{1}
        \hexcellshaded{a}{2}
        \hexcellshaded{a}{5}
        \hexcellshaded{b}{3}
        \hexcellshaded{b}{4}
        \hexcellshaded{b}{5}
        \hexcellshaded{b}{6}
        \hexcellshaded{c}{1}
        \hexcellshaded{c}{2}
        \hexcellshaded{c}{5}
        \hexcellshaded{d}{1}
        \hexcellshaded{d}{3}
        \hexcellshaded{d}{5}
        \hexcellshaded{e}{2}
        \hexcellshaded{e}{6}
        \hexcellshaded{f}{1}
        \hexcellshaded{f}{2}
        \hexcellshaded{f}{4}
        \hexcellshaded{f}{5}
        
        % draw the board
        \hexboard{6}
        
        % draw a path across the board
        % \hexconnect is a hexboard command that connects two cells. The cell coordinates don't have to refer to a cell that is actually drawn on the board, as in references to e0 and d7 etc.
        \hexconnect{e}{0}{e}{1}
        \hexconnect{e}{1}{d}{2}
        \hexconnect{d}{2}{c}{3}
        \hexconnect{c}{3}{c}{4}
        \hexconnect{c}{4}{d}{4}
        \hexconnect{d}{4}{e}{3}
        \hexconnect{e}{3}{f}{3}
        \hexconnect{f}{3}{e}{4}
        \hexconnect{e}{4}{e}{5}
        \hexconnect{e}{5}{d}{6}
        \hexconnect{d}{6}{d}{7}
        \hexconnect{d}{7}{e}{7}
        \hexconnect{e}{7}{f}{6}
%        \hexconnect{f}{6}{f}{7} % this would draw the last line off the board, but I've replaced it with the arrow head command below
        
        % draw thick border around the right hand side of the path across the board
        % using the custom border commands to draw partial borders around the needed cells
        \toprightcellborder{g}{0}
        \bottomrightcellborder{f}{1}
        \bottomleftcellborder{f}{1}
        \leftcellborder{f}{1}
        \bottomleftcellborder{e}{2}
        \leftcellborder{e}{2}
        \toprightcellborder{e}{2}
        \bottomleftcellborder{d}{3}
        \leftcellborder{d}{3}
        \topleftcellborder{d}{3}
        \toprightcellborder{d}{3}
        \rightcellborder{d}{3}
        \topleftcellborder{f}{2}
        \bottomleftcellborder{f}{3}
        \bottomrightcellborder{f}{3}
        \rightcellborder{f}{3}
        \bottomleftcellborder{f}{4}
        \leftcellborder{f}{4}
        \topleftcellborder{f}{4}
        \leftcellborder{f}{5}
        \toprightcellborder{f}{5}
        \bottomleftcellborder{e}{6}
        \leftcellborder{e}{6}
        \topleftcellborder{e}{6}
        \toprightcellborder{e}{6}
        \rightcellborder{e}{6}
        \bottomrightcellborder{f}{6}
        \rightcellborder{f}{6}
%        \bottomrightcellborder{f}{7} % this would draw the last line off the board, but I've replaced it with the arrow head command below
        
        
        % draw arrow heads pointing off the board
        
        % this is a custom version of the hexboard command \hexconnect with an extra arrowhead from arrows.meta
        % \hexcoord sets \xchor and \ychor to be the centre of the given cell. Then we set two nodes and draw a line between them
        \hexcoord{f}{6}
        \node[minimum size=0,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (A) at (\xchor em,\ychor em) {};
        \hexcoord{f}{7}
        \node[minimum size=0,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (B) at (\xchor em,\ychor em) {};
        \draw[line width=\hexthinline em,line cap=round,dotted,-{Stealth[open]}] (A) -- (B);
        
        % this is a custom version of \bottomrightcellborder with an extra arrowhead from arrows.meta
        \hexcoord{f}{7}
        \draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round,-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]}] (0 em,-0.577350 em) -- (0.5 em,-0.288675 em);
        
    \end{hexpicture}
\end{document}
```